# Rails 4 - Error messages and all database records on same page

Tags: database, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

Few days ago I asked very similar question , but I just still don't know how to do it. What I did is that I created comment section under my posts on my blog, all comments are visible all the time, and I want my application to show all comments also when new comment doesn't pass validation(when there is an error) and I also want to see that error below all database records. I just keep failing to do that.

The problem is that when I don't want my application to show all comments on the same page
(I delete temporarily this part from my learn_webdeb file),

```
<% @mains.each do |a| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= a.title %></td>
                <td><%= a.body %></td>
            </tr>
<% end %>
```

things work perfectly, when new comment doesn't pass validation , error is displayed. But when I want to also display on the same page all database records that were previously saved I get this error:

```
Showing /home/mateusz/Pulpit/Aptana3_Workspace/My_webpage/app/views/mains/learn_webdeb.html.erb where line #33 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #33):

</thead>
<tbody>
<% @mains.each do |a| %>
<tr>
<td><%= a.title %></td>
<td><%= a.body %></td>

Rails.root: /home/mateusz/Pulpit/Aptana3_Workspace/My_webpage
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/mains/learn_webdeb.html.erb:33:in `_app_views_mains_learn_webdeb_html_erb__2599098263892148643_20921680'
app/controllers/mains_controller.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/mains_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

Here you have my controller:

```
class MainsController < ApplicationController
  def learn_webdeb
    @main = Main.new
    @mains = Main.all
  end

  def motivation
  end

  def about
  end

  def books_courses
  end

  def contact
  end

  def create
    @main = Main.new(main_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @main.save
        format.html { redirect_to learn_webdeb_path }
      else
        format.html { render controller: "mains", action: "learn_webdeb" }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    redirect_to :action => "learn_webdeb"
  end

  private

    def main_params
      params.require(:main).permit(:title, :body)
    end

end
```

And important part of my learn_webdeb view file:

```
...

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Comment:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<% @mains.each do |a| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= a.title %></td>
                <td><%= a.body %></td>
            </tr>
<% end %>

    </tbody>
</table>
<%= form_for(@main) do |main| %>
    <div>
        <%= main.label :title %>
        <%= main.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= main.label :body %>
        <%= main.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= main.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>

    <% if @main.errors.any? %>
        <div>
            <% @main.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <p><%= msg %></p>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Could anyone explain me:
1.How to get rid of this error, and show all database records and validation errors on the same page?
2.Why did this error occur, what happened behind the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs because you call this in your controller

`render controller: "mains", action: "learn_webdeb"`

`render <action>` uses instance variables which are available in action where it was called (`create` action in your example) and `@mains` instance variable is not available in your view from this action (since it was defined in `learn_webdeb` action only).

To fix this error you need to call `redirect` instead of `render`:

```
def create
  @main = Main.new(main_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @main.save
      format.html { redirect_to @main }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to learn_webdeb_path }
    end
  end
end
```

And if you need to display your validation errors on the same page you should define `@mains` in your create action and call `render` instead of `redirect`:

```
def create
  @main = Main.new(main_params)
  @mains = Main.all

  respond_to do |format|
    if @main.save
      format.html { redirect_to @main }
    else
      format.html { render :learn_webdeb }
    end
  end
end
```